# How to parse xml with e.target.name

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, target

I want to `parse` the `xml` file through `e.target.name` instead of using the `switch function`. The buttons are put into an `Array` and then in a `for loop` where I add them to `eventlistener`.

Now it looks like this:

```
function samClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (e.target)
    {
        case A0101 :
            p.p.arch_tekst.text = archTekst.archMen.A0101T;
            p.p.arch_opis.text = archTekst.archMen.A0101O;
        break;

        case A0102 :
            p.p.arch_tekst.text = archTekst.archMen.A0102T;
            p.p.arch_opis.text = archTekst.archMen.A0102O;
        break;

        case A0103 :
            p.p.arch_tekst.text = archTekst.archMen.A0103T;
            p.p.arch_opis.text = archTekst.archMen.A0103O;
        break;

        case A0104 :
            p.p.arch_tekst.text = archTekst.archMen.A0104T;
            p.p.arch_opis.text = archTekst.archMen.A0104O;
        break;
    }
}
```

but I wan't to make it work like this:

```
function samClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    p.p.arch_tekst.text = archTekst.archMen.(e.target.name + "T");
    p.p.arch_opis.text = archTekst.archMen.(e.target.name + "O");
}
```

but when I write the code in this way it's not working...

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried `archTekst.archMen[e.target.name + "T"];`?

Comment: Thanks it's working ^^, i new that the problem is how to correct write it! Can you short explain to me when to use this: () and when this: []

Comment: And is it possible to do the same but with a tween:
Something like this:
    
 `var sam4Ou:Tween = new Tween([e.target.name],"alpha",Strong.easeOut,0.2,1,0.5,true);`

Comment: `object.propertyName` equals `object["propertyName"]` equals `p = "propertyName"; object[p]` equals `p = "property"; object[p + "Name"]`. But `object."propertyName"` is a syntax error. Use square brackets on an object like you use them on an array: To access a certain element in that object. Only that object elements are indexed by name (i.e. a string) and array elements are indexed by number.

Comment: There's no need to use the name of a DisplayObject to tween it. Simply pass e.target to the Tween, it is a reference to the object already.